# How do you restart X11/gdm in Fedora

Tags: fedora, services, xorg, reboot

What is the equivalent of `/etc/init.d/gdm resart` in Fedora? What is the proper way to restart X11 and the desktop manager.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable `CTRL + ALT + BACKSPACE` to restart X11 like (if that isn't already turned on):

1. Open the **Keyboard Preferences** dialog either by choosing  **System > Preferences > Keyboard** from the Fedora Main Menu or by running the following command from a terminal:

   gnome-keyboard-properties
2. In the **Keyboard Preferences** dialog, choose the Layouts tab (labeled 1 in the screenshot below) and press the **Layout Options** button (labeled 2 in the screenshot below) to bring up the **Keyboard Layout Options** dialog.

   [image]
3. In the **Keyboard Layout Options** dialog, unfold the tree item “**Key sequence to kill the X server**” (labeled 3 in the screenshot below), and mark the checkbox “**Control + Alt + Backspace**” (labeled 4 in the screenshot below)

   [image]

Comment: No thanks; The blog post is down so this doesn't help at all.

Comment: I added the information from that blogpost.